# Extraction of string from particular tag using java

Tags: java

I am having few tags inside of html. As you can see in below HTML having `<AT></AT>`. So I need to extract text from `<AT></AT> this tag`.

I have followed below approach

1. Written one regex what will extract text from AT tag

Below is testing string::

```
href="<AT>EXTRACT_URL</AT>" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;color: #FFFFFF;">Sign In</a></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr> <a href="<AT>EXTRACT_URL</AT>" target="_blank" title="" class="" target="_blank"> <a href="<AT>EXTRACT_URL</AT>" target="_blank" title="" class="" target="_blank"> <a href="<AT>EXTRACT_URL</AT>" target="_blank" title="" class="" target="_blank">
```

Used below program for extracting text from AT Tag

```
private static final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<AT>(.*)</AT>");

public static String getText(String text) {
    final Matcher matcher = TAG_REGEX.matcher(text);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String url = matcher.group(1);
        
        System.out.println("Extracted URL::"+url);                      
    }   
}
```

Getting output from above program:

```
Extracted URL::EXTRACT_URL</AT>" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;letter-spacing: normal;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;color: #FFFFFF;">Sign In</a></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr> <a href="<AT>EXTRACT_URL</AT>" target="_blank" title="" class="" target="_blank"> <a href="<AT>EXTRACT_URL</AT>" target="_blank" title="" class="" target="_blank"> <a href="<AT>EXTRACT_URL
```

Expected Output:

```
Extracted URL::EXTRACT_URL
Extracted URL::EXTRACT_URL
Extracted URL::EXTRACT_URL
Extracted URL::EXTRACT_URL
```

Why I am not getting expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the `Pattern`

Correct patter in this case would be

```
private static final Pattern TAG_REGEX = Pattern.compile("<AT>(.*?)</AT>");
```

Both will match any sequence of characters but

- `.*` is greedy and will match as much as possible (it will end at the last `</AT>`)
- `.*?` is reluctant and will match as few as possible

More at this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html#difs)

Comment: Can you please explain little bit about this pattern?

Comment: Added into the answer.

Comment: note that reluctant is not understood by every regex flavor. sed does not, and that’s a pity!